# firefox noscript, how do i whitelist *cdn.com

Tags: firefox, noscript, whitelist

I have been trying to figure out how to white list any site that has cdn as its last part.  I have tried a regex in abe advanced user section but that does not seem to help does any one have an idea on how to allow those sites automatically?

Comment: also the main url of the site and domains beginning or ending with static.

Comment: xxxxxxcdn.com  liberspeakcdn.com, amazoncdn.com  or [random string].cloudfrontcdn.com